# d3.select by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am new to d3. I have something defined like this:

```
node = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr('id', function(d){ return d.id; })
            .attr("class", "node")
            .on('mouseover', mouseover_node)
            .on("click", nodeClick);
```

Now in function nodeClick I want to access a node (or circle) with a special id. I am looking for something that I could use like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<maxId;i++) {
    d3.select(the node with id = i).do....
```

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: try d3.select("#" + i)

Comment: It gives me these errors:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: '#56' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your problem is that [`id`s and `name`s *must begin with a letter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). So modify your code to prepend  a string to each `id`, e.g.

```
.attr('id', function(d){ return 'name' + d.id; })
```

Then, you can select a given node by using `d3.select( '#name' + i )`. From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) on D3 selections:

> ... you can select by tag ("div"), class (".awesome"), unique
>   identifier ("#foo"), attribute ("[color=red]"), or containment
>   ("parent child").

Comment: any idea how to do this where attribute < or > then a certain value

Comment: @mireilleraad On the lowest level, you can select all elements you are interested, run a `for` loop and pick out those elements that qualify your criteria. for instance: `var all_elements = $('.line'); var line_num_big = []; for (var i = 0; i < all_elements.length; i++) { if (parseInt ($(all_elements[i]).attr('id') > 1000) { line_num_big.push(all_elements[i]); }`. Pardon the formatting, writing all in one line is not fun.

Comment: The docs moved. Permalink to the last version is [Docs @ commit 434aee](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections/434aeefd362e0b132257977a0ef7af4133544919).

Comment: `d3.select("[id='" + i + "']")` looks useful but is there a way to specify multiple conditions? Say id = 1 and sid = 2?